# datacontract serializer decimal formatting

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I having a situation that I need to consume Wcf service using datacontract serialization. So I created sample wcf application and mocked some data like below,

```
return new Obj {
TotalAmount1 = (decimal)268.20,
TotalAmount2 = (decimal)12.00,
TotalAmount3 = (decimal)268.20,
TotalAmount4 = (decimal)17.55 };

[DataContract]
Class Obj
{
[DataMember]
public Decimal TotalAmount1 {get; set;}
[DataMember]
public Decimal TotalAmount2 {get; set;}
[DataMember]
public Decimal TotalAmount3 {get; set;}
[DataMember]
public Decimal TotalAmount4 {get; set;}
}
```

Now,
While consuming this result from client having values like this,

```
{
TotalAmount1 = 268.2,
TotalAmount2 = 12.0,
TotalAmount3 = 268.2,
TotalAmount4 = 17.55 };
```

The Last "0" is missing in TotalAmount1 , TotalAmount2, TotalAmount3.
If I have Non Zero values then its working fine.

Now, I need TotalAmount1 should be like "268.20". How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = decimalValue.ToString("F");
```

If you want to override the default decimal `ToString()` behaviour, you have to create your own class Type.

// edit
If you want to serialize decimal with additional formatting you can do a trick. Maybe you find it useful.

```
public decimal TotalAmount1 { get; set; }
[DataMember(Name = "TotalAmount1")]
private string TotalAmount1Serialized { get; set; }

[OnSerializing]
void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
{
    this.TotalAmount1Serialized = TotalAmount1.ToString("F");
}

[OnDeserialized]
void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
{
    this.PerformanceDate = (...)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just want to know in my wcf server I can see return values as "268.20" but after serialization  in consumer end i can see only "268.2". How can i persist decimal as "268.20"  in client also.

Comment: I've added additional solution

Answer (score 0):

```
string viewTotalAmount1 = String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalAmount1);
```

Comment: Thanks.. But the data type should be decimal.

Comment: Adding trailing 0's to a numeric is formatting, not part of the type. I assume you are displaying the values, no? If you are displaying them, then what difference does it matter if you format them using standard formatting for decimals?

Comment: I am using SOA. So after consuming this I will forward this value to my consumer. So I dont want to change that as String. Another thing is, I am having expected result as "268.20". When I am doing unit test i need to Assert this "268.20" with "268.2". Here my test always failing.

Comment: Again... that is a formatting problem, not a decimal type issue.